# ¿Por qué el recyclerview aparece con las posiciones tan grandes?

Tags: android

Mi pregunta es porque el recyclerview aparece con las posiciones tan grandes? como se puede ver en el video:

https://youtu.be/6x4fFbdPhU8

este es mi código:

```
public class indicelp extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_indicelp);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            toolbar.setTitle("Indice");
        }


        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lylrv);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.addItemDecoration(
                new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        List<Unidades> listaunidades = Arrays.asList(new Unidades("texto unidad 1", "Unidad 1"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 2", "Unidad 2"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 3", "Unidad 3"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 4", "Unidad 4"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 5", "Unidad 5"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 6", "Unidad 6"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 7", "Unidad 7"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 8", "Unidad 8"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 9", "Unidad 9"),
                new Unidades("texto unidad 10", "Unidad 10")
        );
        Adaptador adapter = new Adaptador(listaunidades);

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                if (position == 0) {

                }
            }
        }));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No se entiende cual es la pregunta/el problema... podrías explicarte? editando la pregunta...

Comment: no entiendo yo porque se cerro esta pregunta, tal vez después se edito esta pregunta pero creo que es claro lo se pregunta. =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen 3 cosas que puedes revisar,

1) Primeramente revisa las propiedades de tu `RecyclerView`, ya que puedes definir las propiedades `wrap_content`, `match_parent` o una medida fija, la cual puedes variar de acuerdo a tus necesidades:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/images"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    >
```

Recuerda que si tienes definida la propiedad `android:height="match_parent"` la altura se ajusta a la medida del contenedor `"padre"`.

2) Si extiendes de:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriaAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

debes revisar el mètodo `onBindViewHolder()` ya que puede estar sobreescribiendo su altura:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder vh, int position) {
vh.recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = miAltura;
...  
...
```

3) Algo importante es revisar si tienes la propiedad:

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

ya que determina que las medidas del contenedor a reciclar siempre es la misma y aunque la quieras modificar posteriormente no funcionara.

4) Algo que tambièn podrìa modificar la medida es que estas definiendo un layoutManager

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_categoria);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(getLayoutManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

Con posiciones grandes, te refieres que el item ocupa la altura de todo el `RecycleView`.

Si es eso, revisa tu `xml` donde se definen los items de dentro del recycleview

comprueba los valores `height`
puede que tengas algo así
`android:height="match_parent"`

Para solucionarlo lo debes asignar como `wrap_content` o bien un valor fijo

Answer (score 1):

A mi me paso lo mismo con ImageView y lo que hice fue modificar el tamaño del LinearLayout principal

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="110dp" //Es el ancho de mi ImageView 
android:layout_height="150dp"  //Es el alto de mi ImageView
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
/>

</LienarLayout>
```

Asi se acomodaran los items a la medida que quieras.